# What does "if($_GET['name'])" mean?

Tags: php, if-statement, get, isset

What does `if($_GET['name'])` mean? 
Is this equal to `if(isset($_GET['name']))`?

I really can't find anything in google, so i hope you can help me.
Thank you.

Comment: All your answers here http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: A forum is not the right place to learn a new language.

Comment: This is really the basics. Start here: http://php.net/tut.php Oh, and to answer your question: first `if` condition checks if `$_GET['name']` is `TRUE` and the second one checks if `$_GET['name']` is set (defined).

Answer (score 1):

This just checks to see if `$_GET['name']` is non false. I.e. it is set and not empty, the empty string, `0` e.t.c.

More information [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).